# Comparing date between two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table like this:

**table's name:** temp_pelamardoktorjk

[image]

I also have table like this:

**table's name:** updatingfortables

[image]

I want to compare the date time between **temp_pelamardoktorjk** and **updatingfortables** table. If ***last_update*** (in temp_pelamardoktorjk table) > **generatedTime** (in *updatingfortables' table*) at least one row (I mean all rows in *temp_pelamardoktorjk table* have the "last_update" date. If there is at least one **last_update** which is more than **generated time** then the result will display "update" in the table), if **last_update** <= **generatedTime** then not update. I expect the result like the picture below:

[image]

Maybe, the the result can be made by creating the view table. Could anyone please help me to solve this? Thanks in advance

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: the problem is different @Strawberry

Comment: That's obviously not true.